# how to get available emails quota in sendgrid through marketing email api in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sendgrid

I use gem 'sendgrid_toolkit', '>= 1.1.1'. I want to get my daily email sending limit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good to know. I appreciate. What **we want** to know is...what you tried so far?

Comment: I follow this http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/libraries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to get the number of email remaining on your plan with the SendGrid API at present (as a standard SendGrid User). You can, however, use the [General Statistics](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/index.html) endpoint and it's parameter `requests`. You may then subtract `requests` from the number of emails you have in your plan.

Doing so would look something like:

```
total_credits = 100000
statistics = SendgridToolkit::Statistics.new(api_user, api_key)
stats = statistics.retrieve_aggregate(:start_date => Date.today.beginning_of_month, :end_date => Date.today.end_of_month)
credits_left = total_credits - stats[:requests]

p credits_left
```

*As an additional note, I wouldn't worry too much about going over your credit limit as at present overages are billed at 1¢ per 1,000 emails.*