# Retrieve Credits in SendGrid with PHP

Tags: php, sendgrid, transactional-email

I am attempting to build a sales platform with sendgrid integration, currently due to cost limitations I want to limit email transactions to sendgrid's free plan of 400 emails/day.

Is there a way I can retrieve the remaining email quota programmatically in PHP?

I have seen this question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779219/how-to-get-available-emails-quota-in-sendgrid-through-marketing-email-api-in-rub)) but I am not familiar with ruby, i believe that this is a workaround.

Comment: Looks like you could create a subuser and use this API: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Customer_Subuser_API/account_limits.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set up the user as a subuser of the main account, and then use the [Customer Subuser API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Customer_Subuser_API/account_limits.html) to check/limit the credits. However, the Customer Subuser API is only available to customers on [SendGrid's Silver plan and higher](https://sendgrid.com/transactional-email/pricing), so if you're on the free plan, you won't be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the clarification, I have now moved onto the pay as you go lite plan so i can build reputation and allow for overusage.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to retrieve the quota; it can be inferred by knowing how many you get a day (resets at 00:00 PT), and subtract what you've sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve the credit quota, but SendGrid will error out and the response will say that you've exceeded your credits.

Just keep sending and stop when it errors out.